# Project manager or someone else must confirm code before checkin on TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I think the title explains what i need. We have a very big development department. Everyone checkins and checkouts codes on TFS. But before the checkin operation, an administrator or project manager (or some desired people) must control the code and then confirm or cancel the checkin operation. Because some codes may be incorrect or dangerous. Do you know a tool like that for TFS?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably can do it customizing your process on TFS/VS but what we use where I work is:

1) developer does changes and instead of check in, creates a shelveset.

2) manager check shevesets and checkin or send it back to the developer for some rework.

It works fine as long everybody respects the process.

You can have a look on shelvesets here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181403(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope it helps.